# Ошибка No Resources Specified JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, maven, fxml

Проект на JavaFX.Структура создана с помощью Maven(плагин com.zenjava:javafx-maven-plugin).Все fxml лежат в resources. Почему он не видит мой fxml?

**Код:**

```
public void startMenuStage(Stage MainMenuStage) throws IOException {
    String fxmlFile = "/fxml/Menu.fxml";
    FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader();
    Parent root = fxmlLoader.load(getClass().getResourceAsStream(fxmlFile));
    fxmlLoader.getController();

    MainMenuController mainMenuController = (MainMenuController) fxmlLoader.getController();
    mainMenuController.CloseMenu(MainMenuStage);

    MainMenuScene = new Scene(root, 1280, 720 );
    MainMenuScene.getStylesheets().add("/styles/StyleMenu.css");
    MainMenuStage.setTitle("v.0.1.5.alpha");
    MainMenuStage.setScene(MainMenuScene);
    MainMenuStage.show();
    }
```

Ошибка:

> javafx.fxml.LoadException: No resources specified. unknown path:42

**Структура:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А если убрать `/` в начале или использовать полный путь?

Comment: https://cdn1.savepice.ru/uploads/2017/10/14/1d6c94b60c81f07404c4e47c669c270b-full.jpg

Comment: У меня микроскоп в ремонте.

Comment: http://ipic.su/img/img7/fs/suLc9RU46hc.1508003618.jpg

Comment: Можно прибавить ctrl + +.Текстом могу)

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: inputStream is null.
Вот такая ошибка после того как прописал полный путь

Comment: директория fxml должна находится на том же уровне вложенности где и класс со startMenuStage или делай "../../../fxml/Menu.fxml" пока не дойдешь на верного каталога

Comment: Ошибка inputStream is null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в самом FXML. В нем прописывался файл локализации Locate и при загрузке, он не мог видеть эти Locate и писал эту ошибку.При перемещении файлов локализации в нужный каталог,все заработало!